# Leetcode Segmentation fault trying to reset hashtable data structure between calls (partially solved)

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, segmentation-fault, hashtable

I'm doing a [problem](https://leetcode.com/problems/first-missing-positive/) on Leetcode. It says I passed my first test case but I failed my second with a simple wrong answer. When I ran that case manually, I passed, so I know it's something to do with data persistence between their runs. It's obviously the hash table I'm using, which I first declared globally. To fix, I first tried resetting to zero with calloc and memset but I got segfault errors.

I decided the logical thing is to create the hash inside the caller function, so each time it's called it would be reinitalized. However, I am still getting seg fault errors (address sanitizer deadly signal) even though it seems like it should work. Am I misusing pointers?

Here is my code that's not working. The comments //\ represent lines of code I had before, where it did work case by case. There were not many changes- mostly to return the hash. I comment where the seg fault occurs (per my printf debugging). I hope I didn't miss anything. I'm trying to display two coding instanecs in one because it's mostly reduntant.

```
#define SIZE 1000

typedef struct htent{
    struct htent* next;
    int key, value;
    
} htent;

int hashf(int val, int size){
    return val % SIZE; // don't need anything fancy
}

htent* create_new_htent(int val){ // the value is its own key
    htent* ent = malloc(sizeof(htent));
    ent->next = NULL;
    ent->key = val;
    ent->value = val;
    return ent;
}
// htent* ht[SIZE] = {0}; //\\ This was my method before (main difference)
htent* build_hash_table_n_get_lowest(int* nums, int numsSize, int* low){ //\\ returned void before
    htent* ht[SIZE] = {0}; //\\ before was commented out
    int hash;
    int running_low = 10000; // large #
    htent* tmp;
    for (int i = 0; i < numsSize; i++){
        if (nums[i] < 1 ) continue; // drop negatives
        if (nums[i] < running_low) running_low = nums[i];
        printf("%d: Running Low %d\n", i, running_low);
        htent* ent = create_new_htent(nums[i]);
        hash = hashf(nums[i], numsSize);
        if (ht[hash] == NULL){ 
            ht[hash] = ent; // singly linked list 
            continue;
        }
        tmp = ht[hash];
        while(tmp->next != NULL){
            tmp = tmp->next;
        }
        tmp->next = ent;
    }
    *low = running_low;
    return ht; //\\ was commented out before
}
    
int find_missing_lowest(htent** ht, int numsSize, int lowest){
    int moving_target = 1;
    for (int i = 0; i<numsSize; i++){
        if (ht[moving_target] == NULL){   // SEG FAULTS HERE!!!
         return moving_target;
        }
        moving_target++;
    }
    return moving_target;
}
    

int firstMissingPositive(int* nums, int numsSize){ // Function Leetcode calls 
    int lowest;
    htent* ht = build_hash_table_n_get_lowest(nums, numsSize, &lowest); // tried with htent**
    return find_missing_lowest(ht, numsSize, lowest);
    
    
    }
```

EDIT: I built this function using the global scope approach and it works and these tests pass (just have to handle edge cases), but there has to be a better way;

```
void refresh_hashtable(){
    for (int i = 0; i<SIZE; i++){
        ht[i] = NULL;
    }
}
```

Comment: `if (nums[i] < 1 ) continue;` this drops `0` and `1` also, is that what you want?

Comment: Yes, for the challenge, we ignore all <=0. The above should allow 1. BTW I got my code passing in 4ms, just with a few changes specifically related to running through the chained linked list, but to pass I have to use the global hash table variable and reset it manually via iteration. I still don't know why I get seg faults when I try create it inside a function or use memset.